# Weird String Comparison Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

The "currentPasswordBox" is a UITextField.

```
    if (currentPasswordBox.text == @"1234") {

        NSLog(@"Correct");

    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Incorrect");
    }



}
```

The Log says (when I type 1234 into the UITextField) "Incorrect"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

== will do a pointer compare, which is not correct. You want

```
if ([currentPasswordBox.text isEqualToString:@"1234"]) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (I am a noob :P)

Comment: You can also use `caseInsensitiveCompare:` if you are worried about case.